# Infyom Swagger : Issue with path parameter

Tags: laravel, swagger, laravel-6, swagger-php, infyom

I have setup Infyom laravel and created API successfully.

I have also set up the "appointer/swaggervel" and generated the swagger URL as well.

The issue is with the API URL which is pointing right now as shown in the below image.

I have to call the full URL like : http://localhost:8080/project_folder/public/api/glasses

Currrently it pointing to : http://localhost:8080/api/glasses

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because I wasn't run the below command.

> php artisan serve

Once I run above command I face issue regarding the **server.php** file.

This error happens because the **server.php** file is missing in your application. 
Maybe it is **deleted** or **removed** from your project directory.

Just add the **server.php** file at the ***root*** of your project.

This process helps me to run the API URL and it works for me.